# A data type of (JSON + JQ) is a functor?

Tags: json, jq, functor

## Question

If there is a data type which stores a JSON string and offers all the JQ filters as the function for its fmap method to apply on the JSON, then the data type will be a functor. Is it correct?

JQ filter takes an a sequence of whitespace-separated JSON values, apply a transformation function, and generates a sequence of whitespace-separated JSON data.

> It’s important to remember that every filter has an input and an output. Even literals like “hello” or 42 are filters - they take an input but always produce the same literal as output.
>
> The input to jq is parsed as a sequence of whitespace-separated JSON values which are passed through the provided filter one at a time. The output(s) of the filter are written to standard out, again as a sequence of whitespace-separated JSON data.

- [Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html)
- [Understanding functor laws: is this a functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958881/understanding-functor-laws-is-this-a-functor)

Comment: `jq` is more like Haskell `($)`; it takes a filter (a function of type `JSON -> JSON`) and a `JSON`, and produces another `JSON`.

Comment: A functor is *two* mappings: `f :: Type -> Type` and `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. What plays the role of `f` in your analogy?

Comment: As a concrete example, you can use `fmap` with `String` in Haskell (because `String == [Char]`), but not `Text` (`[]` is parameterized by `Char`, but `Text` isn't parameterized at all).